# Trouble with multiline if statments in OCaml

Tags: if-statement, functional-programming, ocaml, expected-exception

I wasn't able to find a clear answer on Google, but it seems multiline if-statements are discouraged in OCaml (?) The ones I see with multiple lines seem to have `begin end` keywords in them.

I'm currently getting this error on the line `num = (num - temp) / 10`, characters 25-27 : `Error: Parse error: "end" expected after [sequence] (in [expr])`. If I remove all of the `begin end` then I get the error `Error: This expression has type bool but an expression was expected of type int` at the same line.

```
let rec reverse_int num =
  if num / 10 == 0 then begin
    num
  end else begin
    let temp = num mod 10 in
    num = (num - temp) / 10

    let numDigits = string_of_int num

    temp * (10 * String.length(numDigits)) + reverse_int num
  end;;
```

Comment: (1) the recursive call uses `rev_int`, should be `reverse_int`, (2) have you tried adding `let...in` to `num = (num - temp) / 10` and an `in` after `let numDigits = string_of_int num`? I added those and it compiles.

Comment: Sorry, in my code it's all rev_int. I just changed it in StackOverflow to show clearer what the method does, but I forgot to change the second one in this post.

Comment: Thank you! Compiles now, I was also wondering why the `let...in` for `num =` is necessary?

Comment: You're trying to declare a local variable to hold some temporary value. It will hold this value not globally, but in an expression that follows, so you specify the expression by saying (let identifier `num` stand for the following quotient in the expression that follows `in`). More experienced folks will give a more satisfying answer. That's my guess; could be wrong.

Comment: I'm confused on why t it's not using `num` from the function's argument

Comment: Variables in ocaml are *immutable*, so you can't just assign to `num`. You can temporarily shadow it by a nested `let` as you now have, but to modify a variable you should look into references/assignables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably mean something like the following.

```
let rec reverse_int num =
  if num / 10 == 0 then begin
    num
  end else begin
    let temp = num mod 10 in
    let num = (num - temp) / 10 in

    let numDigits = string_of_int num in

    temp * (10 * String.length(numDigits)) + reverse_int num
end;;
```

Problems here:

- line `num = (num - temp) / 10` is a value of type boolean. What you mean is that you want, in what follows, `num` to have the *new* value `(num - temp) / 10` and continue evaluation; hence replace this line with `let num = (num - temp) / 10 in`.
- lines 
   `let numDigits = string_of_int num
   temp * (10 * String.length(numDigits)) + reverse_int num`
  are parsed `let numDigits = string_of_int num temp *...` which yields a type error, as the function `string_of_int` only has one argument. Here the `in` is necessary.